# Evaluating \luaexec while writing to the aux file

Tags: luatex, auxiliary-files, write

In the document end hook I'm trying to write `\luaexec{x = 1}` to the aux file, where the `1` is computed in Lua itself (and more complex in the real document, of course).  MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\luaexec{x = 0}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \noexpand\luaexec{x = \luaexec{tex.sprint(1)}}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

x = \luaexec{tex.sprint(x)}

\end{document}
```

Here are just some of the many errors I get from `lualatex`:

```
[...]
Runaway argument?
{x = \begingroup \escapechar 92 \newlinechar 10 \edef \protect \let \relax \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \luaexec was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.5


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
[...]
l.6 S
   ee the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
\inaccessible
l.7 ...ken \let \edef \def document{document}\edef {
                                                   on input line 18}\protect...
! Improper \spacefactor.
\@o-\spacefactor
                 \@m
[...]
```

I assume this is because of the amusing stuff being written into my aux file, such as:

```
\relax
\luaexec {x = \begingroup \escapechar 92 \newlinechar 10 \edef \protect \let \relax \let \relax \let \reserved@d =*\def \def document{document}\edef { on input line 18}\protect \begingroup \immediate \write \@unused   \def \MessageBreak
 \let \protect \edef  Your command was ignored.\MessageBreak Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,\MessageBreak or  <return>  to continue without it.  \errhelp \let \def \MessageBreak
                \def   \errmessage  LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

I tried this as well, but it fails in its own way:

```
\AtEndDocument{%
  \edef\myCode{\noexpand\luaexec{x = \luaexec{tex.sprint(1)}}}
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\myCode}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is it just hopeless to think that I can use `\luaexec` here?  Thanks!

Comment: What would you want to be written in the `.aux` file? Note that `\write` doesn't do command execution, but just expansion.

Comment: I expected my MWE to write `\luaexec{x = 1}` into the `.aux` file, where the `1` is computed in some Lua code.

Comment: `\luaexec` is not expandable: if you want to use Lua in such a context you'll need the `\directlua` primitive.

Comment: I have just now noticed the footnote in the luacode documentation, saying that `\luaexec` is "not purely expandable."  I assume that's what @JosephWright is referring to as well.  I don't understand "expandable-ness" and when/where it matters, but I can certainly understand "you need something expandable there and `\luaexec` is not."  I'd be happy to select this as the answer if you'd post it.  Thank you!

Comment: `\luadirect` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\luaexec` is not expandable, but `\luadirect` is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\luaexec{x = 0}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \noexpand\luaexec{x = \luadirect{tex.sprint(1)}}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

x = \luaexec{tex.sprint(x)}

\end{document}
```

At the second run,

> x = 1

is printed.